# make Sharepoint list search webpart show results only on search

Tags: 2013, search

I have added a sharepoint 2013 `list view webpart`

When the page loads, it is bringing the items from the list

I have selected "Enable Search" in webpart properties and its showing the search box on top. But the problem is it is bring the view during the page load.

I want it to fetch items only on search

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your query transform in your search webpart

```
?{searchboxquery}
```

Or if you already have a query transform wrap it within this

```
{?{searchterms} QueryTransform}
```

Comment: its actually a list webpart with search box shown 
which webpart should be used for this?

Comment: Are you using the ListView Webparts on the list forms?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This approach is when you are using search results web part

Comment: Content query webpart?

Comment: For your case one OOTB way would be to use the ListView webpart and the text filter webpart together.Send the text filter values to the List webpart using connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54930/discussion-between-rjv91-and-vignesh).